# Measuring the width of a verbatiminput block

Tags: verbatim, external-files, width

Is there any way of measuring the width of a VerbatimInput block?

In other words, I would like something along the following lines, except that the verbatim data should be taken from an external file as with \VerbatimInput:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

% Get the verbatim data from an external file instead.
\SaveVerb{data}+verbatim text }&^+

\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{\UseVerb{data}}

Width is: \the\mylength.

\end{document}
```

(Saving the verbatim block is not crucial to me so if there is some completely different way of measuring its width that would also be fine.  I also don't insist on using the \fancyvrb package if there is another verbatim package that does this.)

Answer (score 4):

Your code actually works and will also work with listings. Better include a frame to see what is happening.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{verbatim.tex}
This is some verbatim .
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{\lstinputlisting{verbatim.tex}}
Width is: \the\mylength.\par
\fbox{\lstinputlisting{verbatim.tex}}
\end{document}
```

As you change the contents of the file (which I saved with filecontents) you will see the length changing.

Comment: Thanks, that works great!  Just one follow-up question: if I understand you correctly you are saying that this would also work with fancyvrb (which I would slightly prefer over listings in this case), but if in your code snippet above I replace \lstinputlisting with \VerbatimInput I get a "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." error in the \settowidth command.

Comment: @PerAustrin It is due to `\fbox`. Please replace with `\fbox{\hbox to \mylength{\vbox{\VerbatimInput{verbatim.tex}}}}` and everything will work out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\savebox{\mybox}{<content>}` (need `\newsavebox\mybox` first) to store anything in an horizontal box and then access its width using `\wd\mybox`. Actually `\settowidth` does something like that.

The problem with `\VerbatimInput` from `fancyvrb` is that it inserts the verbatim text as paragraph which will cause trouble in the restricted horizontal mode forced by a savebox *and* will force the width of the content to `\linewidth` anyway! Therefore you need to find some other command to input the verbatim text without forming a full paragraph. I'm not sure with verbatim package allow you to insert single-line verbatim content from an external file without forming a paragraph.
However you could use the following command I just wrote which uses the usual verbatim related settings to do the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\makeatletter
% Saves single line verbatim content into savebox from a file
\newcommand{\SaveVerbInput}[1]{%
    \sbox{\mybox}{{%
        \let\do\@makeother
        \dospecials
        \@vobeyspaces
        \frenchspacing
        \@noligs
        \verbatim@font
        \input{#1}%
    }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\SaveVerbInput{v}

Width is: \the\wd\mybox.

Text is: \usebox{\mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately my files have more than one line so this does not quite solve my problem.

Comment: @PerAustrin: Ok, then I misunderstood your question slightly. Your example made it look like you are working with small inline verbatim texts.